# ORDER BY SQL how to deal with same values?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have the following table for example

```
ID      value1       value2
1        10            12
2        14            15
3        14            19
4        19            20
```

With my SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY value1 DESC
```

If the number in value1 is the same as another (e.g. in rows 2 and 3)

How can I then order by value2 ASC?

i.e. the final order will be

```
ID      value1       value2
4        19            20
2        14            15
3        14            19
1        10            12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just append with comma, the priority is left to right.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY value1 DESC, value2 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)?

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY value1 DESC, value2 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one more column in your order like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY value1 DESC, value2 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY value1 DESC, value2 ASC
```

Here what will happens is data will be sorted from left to right manner.
So this will first sort in descending by value1 and then sort in ascending by value2

-

Thanks